# Android studio package management error when running

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm new to the Android development so I was trying to set up a simple project using kotlin.
I am working on an M2 macbook trying to use a Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_arm64-v8a emulator.
My project was literally the default project opened after creating a new project in Android Studio.

I tried to run the app but it keeps failing and doesn't really give much insight into the problem.
I got the following notifications, 'Error running 'app': The application could not be installed.' , and 'Run app: Installation failed Suggested action:' only there is no suggested action. I also get this notification

> package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 5636734` returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package' indicating there is a problem with the Android Package manager (PackageManager) service.

I don't understand the problem with the app because I have made no changes to the initial project.
How do I fix the set up so I can run the project?